# Usage of cvMatchTemplate() function in Opncv

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

Can I match two images which looks same but not 100% same ,Using cvMatchTemplate() function in Opncv.?

As a example there are 5 images on DB which represent no1,no2,no3,no4 and no5 by using my left hand. And you shows no3 by using your left hand. I want to filter My no3 image from DB as the result. 
In this scenario your hand size ,your hand color and your representation will not match 100% with me.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6218956/176769

Answer (score 1):

With `cvMatchTemplate()` function you cannot match two similar images. But what this function basically does is matches a template image to the main image and based on this provides the result.

As an example assume face detection technique, wherein you have a face images and out of it you want to detect the location of eyes. Hence you load template images of eyes and try to match it with the face image to detect the position of the eyes.

This is what my understanding is about this function.